# How to combine a key point detector and a key point descriptor to match images in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, feature-detection, sift

I would like to try combination of 3 different key points detectors(Harris, MSER, DOG) and 3 different feature descriptors(SIFT, PCA-SIFT, GLOH) to local feature match 2 images in MATLAB.
For instance, when matching two images I would like to try the combination of

- match_points(Harris, SIFT)
- match_points(Harris, PCA-SIFT)
- match_points(Harris, GLOH)
- match_points(MSER, SIFT)
- ...
- match_points(DOG, SIFT)
- ...

so that I can compare matching scores. I am thinking of using ration test to get matching scores.

I know that we can extract HOG features in MATLAB using;

```
[featureVector,hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures (img);
```

For MSER key points;

```
points = detectMSERFeatures(I);
```

For Harris key points;

```
corners = detectHarrisFeatures(gr);
```

However, I don't know how can I combine a key point detector and a key point descriptor such as described above in MATLAB?

Thank you.

Comment: So, you want to try do descrive the detected points better?

Comment: I want to describe detected points with various descriptors such as SIFT, PCA-SIFT, and GLOH.

Comment: You probably need to have the code for that. I believe MATLAB's inbuild feature descriptors will give you the best feature on an image, not a feature per data inputed. This makes sense as e.g. SIFT will store 128 values per pixel, making the data very very big. I think you need to write your own code, or find a code that does compute SIFT for each of the data points

Comment: Could you please give a code example, if you have? @Ander Biguri

Comment: ehhhh, thats a large piece of code you are asking mate. But no, i do not have it.

Comment: thank you anyways. But the problem is I still have no answer to my question

Comment: Ah, but you are wrong! you have an answer to how to do it. unfortunately the answer is: " you need to find your own way, either code it yourself or find code somewhere". No one is going to code it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extractFeatures`.  It supports SURF, BRISK, and FREAK descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dima. Can I provide detected points to extractFeatures method?

Comment: Of course.   In fact, that is the required input. Please type `doc extractFeatures` at the matlab and read the documentation.